# How to get Client System Details using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get Client System details, I tried getting data  IP Address, Country,State, Location, etc. But still, I need a few more info like... Client System Name, Client OS and Client timestamp. How can I get all these Info using Javascript.

Code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Get User Details IP Address, city, country, state, latitude, longitude </title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var strip, strcountry, strcity, strregion, strlatitude, strlongitude, strtimezone

        function GetUserInfo(data) {
            alert(data.hostname);
            strip = data.host;
            strcountry = data.countryName;
            strcity = data.city;
            strregion = data.region;
            strlatitude = data.latitude;
            strlongitude = data.longitude;
            strtimezone = data.timezone;
        }
        $(function() {
            BindUserInfo();
        })

        function BindUserInfo() {
            document.getElementById('lblIP').value = strip;
            document.getElementById('lblCountry').value = strcountry;
            document.getElementById('lblCity').value = strcity;
            document.getElementById('lblregion').value = strregion;
            document.getElementById('lbllatitude').value = strlatitude;
            document.getElementById('lbllongitude').value = strlongitude;
            document.getElementById('lbltimezone').value = strtimezone;
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=GetUserInfo"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="lblIP" value="" />
                    <input type="text" id="lblCountry" value="" />
                    <input type="text" id="lblCity" value="" />
                    <input type="text" id="lblregion" value="" />
                    <input type="text" id="lbllatitude" value="" />
                    <input type="text" id="lbllongitude" value="" />
                    <input type="text" id="lbltimezone" value="" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

### Client OS:

```
String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
```

You can get a full list of all user-agent values from this web site, http://www.user-agents.org/

### Javascript Way :

```
var OSName="Unknown OS";

if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";

if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";

if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";

if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";
```

and send the OSName variable back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

### Client System Name:

You can do it with IE 'sometimes' as I have done this for an internal application on an intranet which is IE only. Try the following:

```
function GetComputerName()

{

    try
    {
        var network = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Network');
        // Show a pop up if it works
        alert(network.computerName);
    }
    catch (e) { }
}
```

It may or may not require some specific security setting setup in IE as well to allow the browser to access the ActiveX object.

Comment: Why are you posting different answers??Post all at once in a single answer..and your solution is incorrect..

Answer (score -2):

### Client TimeStamp :

In JavaScript? Just instantiate a new Date object
now = new Date();
That will create a new Date object with the client's local time.